# AngularJs - After element is removed/destroyed cleanup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Scenario

I have a directive that wraps the target element in a div to contain the other UI elements that get created with the directive, my problem is that when I try to unwrap the source element when it is about to be destroyed/removed from the DOM, it causes the browser to enter into an infinite loop.

### Sample

This is a sample code that reproduces the problem:

```
angular.module('myDirective', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      function wrapElement() {
        element.wrap('<div class="my-directive-container"></div>');
      }

      function unwrapElement() {
        element.parent().replaceWith(element);
      }

      // Listen for the destroy event on the element
      element.on('$destroy', unwrapElement);

      wrapElement();
    }
  };
});
```

### Problem

My question is, how can I unwrap or get rid of the container element after the source element has been removed?

### Fiddle

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu6e3L9c/1/), when you try to remove the element nothing will happen, because the Maximum call stack size exceeded error will show up in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upgrade (at least 1.2.6 apparently), use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `on`, otherwise unregister the handler manually:

```
function unwrapElement() {
    element.off('$destroy', unwrapElement);
    // this could also be just element.parent().remove() instead
    element.parent().replaceWith(element);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ferada, this worked perfect! and the reason I am doing a replace is because the same function can be called manually to destroy the created UI without removing the source element. Cheers!